# Hibernate Select wrong table name

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Im trying to insert and select data in mysql database trough Hibernate and Insert is working fine for me but select somehow dont map the right table name and returns me no result.

Get and insert code:

```
    SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(obj);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    try {
        Session mysession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        mysession.beginTransaction();
        weatherDataObject resultObjectHib = (weatherDataObject) mysession.get(weatherDataObject.class, 26);
        mysession.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sessFact.close();



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="some.pack">
    <class name="weatherCoordinates" table="coordinates">
        <id name="dataBaseId" column="coordinates_id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="lat" type="string" column="coordinates_lat" />
        <property name="lon" type="string" column="coordinates_lon" />




    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>




<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="some.pack">
    <class name="weatherDataObject" table="data_object">
        <id name="id" column="data_object_id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="data_object_name" />
        <many-to-one name="coord" class="task.main.DataObjects.weatherCoordinates"
            column="coordinates_id" unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I see sql execution strings it is :

```
Hibernate: insert into coordinates (coordinates_lat, coordinates_lon) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into data_object (data_object_name, coordinates_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select weatherdat0_.data_object_id as data_obj1_1_0_, weatherdat0_.data_object_name as data_obj2_1_0_, weatherdat0_.coordinates_id as coordina3_1_0_ from data_object weatherdat0_ where weatherdat0_.data_object_id=?
```

The problem is `weatherdat0` that somehow is wrong my table is called the way I mapped it in the file data_object don't know how and why it is changed anybody can help ?

Comment: What is your issue exactly, there is no problem with generated queries right. I am not able to understand the statement `The problem is weatherdat0 that somehow is wrong my table is called the way I mapped it in the file data_object don't know how and why it is changed anybody can help ?`

Comment: Hibernate: select weatherdat0_.data_object_id as data_obj1_1_0_, weatherdat0_.data_object_name as data_obj2_1_0_, weatherdat0_.coordinates_id as coordina3_1_0_ from data_object weatherdat0_ where weatherdat0_.data_object_id=?


weatherdat0_  is not the name of my table and dont retrive any object from database

Comment: `from data_object` the table is correct. Then how you are saying wrong table name?

Comment: If the query is ok than am I doing something wrong, because my object is not created ?

Comment: why don't you hit the database directly and see if the record is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

The query is generated on correct table, as the `select` query is run on table `from data_object`

The `weatherdat0_`is just an alias for the table as mentioned in the `from` statement:

```
from data_object weatherdat0_
```

So it is picking correct table name only.

Now if the query is not returning any results means there are no records matching that `id` so  I suggest you to run the query directly on database and see if it returns any records.